# Not able to run Sitecore7.5 website through VS 2013

Tags: debugging, iis-7.5, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

I have created an instance of Sitecore 7.5.Then create a blank VS 2013 (MVC) solution and copy the properties and .csproj file and put in wwwroot\SitecoreWebsite folder and open this project in VS 2013.
Now when I run this project from IIS it's running properly But when I run through Visual Studio Solution ( i.e. F5) it's started continuously loading and nothing happens.
What should I do now.

Comment: This question looks similar for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913139/sitecore-project-localhost-just-hangs . See if the answer helps

Comment: Sitecore does not support Cassini or IIS Express. You should run from IIS, and then use _Attach to Process_ instead: 2.1.1 IIS Requirements - http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/installation_guide_sc75-a4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Wow!!

Issue resolved:

I did the following steps:

1. Go to project's properties
2. Go to web displayed in left side menu

3.In server I changed to Loca lIIS

4.In project URL enter http://SampleWebsite

Thanks